# Paypal says "merchant integration upgrade information"

Tags: curl, paypal, express-checkout

I am using `Express Checkout` via `Classic API` (i.e. curl based). So today I received an email from paypal saying they are upgrading SSL Certificate and has this pdf:

https://ppmts.custhelp.com/ci/fattach/get/487025/1429638687/redirect/1/filename/2015%20Merchant%20Security%20System%20Upgrade%20Guide%20(U.S.%20English).pdf

Could someone please tell me if there is any need for change in the code that I need to do?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Do one of the following: 
1. Update your software to the latest version that supports SHA-256. 
2. If a key store is used for certificate validation/authentication, install the VeriSign G5 Root Certificate into your keystore. 
    Append code to .cert file -- https://knowledge.symantec.com/support/mpki-for-ssl-support/index?page=content&actp=CROSSLINK&id=SO5624